# Make text input unselectable for touchscreens?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, input, touchscreen

Im using jQuery UI to make a range slider. The plugin creates a text input in the html to display the range value. The issue is the text area is selectable on touchscreen devices, even if its not then editable.

How can I stop the text input being selectable? Ive tried the following CSS:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$("#amount, #amount2").mousedown(function (evt) {
       evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
       return false;
   });

$("#amount, #amount2").disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the CSS `user-select` CSS approach *does* work (at least in Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04:

```
#amount {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    outline: none;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hBm9f/).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You could create your own `disableSelection()` like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ 
        disableSelection : function() { 
                return this.each(function() { 
                        this.onselectstart = function() { return false; }; 
                        this.unselectable = "on"; 
                        jQuery(this).css('user-select', 'none'); 
                        jQuery(this).css('-o-user-select', 'none'); 
                        jQuery(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none'); 
                        jQuery(this).css('-khtml-user-select', 'none'); 
                        jQuery(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none'); 
                }); 
        } 
});
```

Use like this:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 ){
 // touch screen detected
 $("#amount, #amount2").disableSelection(); 
}
```

Comment: Ive tried using disableSelection without any conditionals and it doenst work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit clumsy but ive found a solution that works. Ive just positioned divs with no content over the input so its not selectable but looks and behaves like a normal input in every other way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to not use a textarea.  Use PHP's GD Library instead to create something that looks like a textarea.